# Is there a function in REDCap to create a question to which the response is a dropdown menu of all the countries in the world?

Tags: redcap

I'm new to REDcap. I would just like to ask if there is a function in REDCap to create a question to which the response is a dropdown menu of all the countries in the world?  I don't want to manually add countries. I'm using the "Multiple choice - Drop-down list (Single best answer)".

Thanks in advance!

Can't find a function for this under action tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such function. What I ended up doing was googling a list of all countries in the world and copy pasting.

Kind of related: this module lets you create a hierachical lookups which I found later and thought would have been cool to explore https://redcap.miami.edu/redcap_v13.1.29/ExternalModules/?prefix=lookup_assistant&page=README.md